# Why is the final return value of j 10, how does LLVM know it

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

i have this code:

```
int main() {
   int i = 0;
   int &j = i;
   j = 10;
   return i;
}
```

and after pass -mem2reg, get the ir as follows:

```
define dso_local i32 @main() #0 !dbg !7 {
entry:
  call void @llvm.dbg.value(metadata i32 0, metadata !11, metadata !DIExpression()), !dbg !12
  call void @llvm.dbg.value(metadata i32* undef, metadata !13, metadata !DIExpression()), !dbg !12
  call void @llvm.dbg.value(metadata i32 10, metadata !11, metadata !DIExpression()), !dbg !12
  ret i32 10, !dbg !15
}
```

What I'm confused about is what analysis LLVM uses to get i and j to be equivalent.
I got the details of this pass runtime:

```
  [2021-12-02 11:53:05.295018000] 0x5626d58d2a20   Executing Pass 'Function Pass Manager' on Module '/usr/local/LLVM/test/e0.ll'...
[2021-12-02 11:53:05.295137300] 0x5626d58bf890     Executing Pass 'Dominator Tree Construction' on Function 'main'...
[2021-12-02 11:53:05.295169500] 0x5626d58bf890     Executing Pass 'Promote Memory to Register' on Function 'main'...
0x5626d58bf330       Required Analyses: Assumption Cache Tracker, Dominator Tree Construction
[2021-12-02 11:53:05.295364900] 0x5626d58bf890     Made Modification 'Promote Memory to Register' on Function 'main'...
0x5626d58bf330       Preserved Analyses: Natural Loop Information, Lazy Branch Probability Analysis, Lazy Block Frequency Analysis, Interval Partition Construction, Post-Dominator Tree Construction, Machine Dominance Frontier Construction, MachineDominator Tree Construction, WebAssembly Exception Information, Spill Code Placement Analysis, Bundle Machine CFG Edges, Machine Natural Loop Construction, Detect single entry single exit regions, Dominance Frontier Construction, View regions of function, Print regions of function to 'dot' file, View regions of function (with no function bodies), MachinePostDominator Tree Construction, Delinearization, Print regions of function to 'dot' file (with no function bodies), Detect single entry single exit regions, Dependence Analysis, Dominator Tree Construction, Dominator Info Printer, Print a call graph, Lazy Machine Block Frequency Analysis, Analysis if a function is memory bound, Strip gc.relocates inserted through RewriteStatepointsForGC, Machine Block Frequency Analysis, Block Frequency Analysis, Basic Alias Analysis (stateless AA impl)
 -*- 'Promote Memory to Register' is the last user of following pass instances. Free these instances
[2021-12-02 11:53:05.295628600] 0x5626d58bf890      Freeing Pass 'Dominator Tree Construction' on Function 'main'...
[2021-12-02 11:53:05.295648400] 0x5626d58bf890      Freeing Pass 'Promote Memory to Register' on Function 'main'...
[2021-12-02 11:53:05.295663100] 0x5626d58bf890     Executing Pass 'Module Verifier' on Function 'main'...
 -*- 'Module Verifier' is the last user of following pass instances. Free these instances
[2021-12-02 11:53:05.295725200] 0x5626d58bf890      Freeing Pass 'Module Verifier' on Function 'main'...
[2021-12-02 11:53:05.295740400] 0x5626d58d2a20   Made Modification 'Function Pass Manager' on Module '/usr/local/LLVM/test/e0.ll'...
 -*- 'Function Pass Manager' is the last user of following pass instances. Free these instances
[2021-12-02 11:53:05.295828100] 0x5626d58d2a20    Freeing Pass 'Assumption Cache Tracker' on Module '/usr/local/LLVM/test/e0.ll'...
[2021-12-02 11:53:05.295850400] 0x5626d58d2a20   Executing Pass 'Print Module IR' on Module '/usr/local/LLVM/test/e0.ll'...
 -*- 'Print Module IR' is the last user of following pass instances. Free these instances
[2021-12-02 11:53:05.299496500] 0x5626d58d2a20    Freeing Pass 'Print Module IR' on Module '/usr/local/LLVM/test/e0.ll'...
```

Can someone help me figure out which analysis or optimization lets LLVM know that i and j are equivalent，very thankful！

Comment: j is a reference to i. Are you expecting a different value? FWIW, GCC returns the same value. https://godbolt.org/z/hPnh1Wv9s

Comment: I would like to know what analysis LLVM has done to come up with the conclusion j is a reference to i. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: j is a reference to i. That's what int& j = i means. That is what the original LLVM IR produced by Clang means as well. https://godbolt.org/z/TKoo45srG What is happening further down the LLVM pipeline is that that is getting simplified to return 10. There is no analysis doing this in LLVM; it's already in the C++ and produced as IR by Clang.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still don't know exactly when it happened. What I see is that when 'ir' is generated under `O0` optimization, the return value is a temporary variable `%1` loaded from `i`.

Comment: Strange. I can emit the optimized IR from clang with -O3 but not from opt with -O3. I'm going to work on this because I should know it (but I'm more backend than middle end).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate unoptimized IR with clang

> clang -S -emit-llvm -Xclang -disable-O0-optnone xx.cpp

Optimize the resulting IR with opt

> opt --print-after-all -O3 xx.ll  -S -o yy.ll

If you look at the IR as it gets optimized you'll see it gets simplified in the [SimplifyCFGPass](https://llvm.org/doxygen/SimplifyCFGPass_8cpp_source.html).

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks very much! Can I ask another question about alias analysis?
For example, `j `and `i` above should be aliases, but alias analysis using LLVM does not lead to such a conclusion. Do you have any good suggestions?

Comment: No, I'm really a backend guy. I generally look at the IR as generated by Clang and the middle end IR optimization passes. You should read the the LLVM docs. https://llvm.org/docs/AliasAnalysis.html